# Cutting / Formatting a docker service command

Tags: bash, docker, sed, grep, cut

Sorry for the imprecise title but i'm actually working on the simpliest way to cut this:

[Docker service ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AM09.png)

Into this:

[Docker service ls cutted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osj8E.png)

Tried with some -f but not working.
Maybe with some grep/sed/cut stuff but i didnt find a satisfying way...

Thanks a lot for the time

Comment: don't post a question with pictures of text.. copy them into question and use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .. and add whatever commands you tried

Comment: I cannot understand the upvote. The Q is hard to read, and it doesn't point to the right problem, also it doesn't tell "what was not working"

Comment: Sorry for everything ! 
Not really comfortable with the stack overflow world...
Subject closed but i will made better formulations / format for my next questions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk

```
docker service ls | awk -F" " '{print $2, $4}'
```